# AVR: Why doesn't my if statement yield TRUE?

Tags: avr

```
int i=0;
DDRD = 0xff;
PORTC = 0xff;  
while (1) 
{ 
    if(PINC5 == 1)
    {...}
```

I have been trying to figure out why the comparison of PC5 pin of PORTC with 1 yields False everytime. I have activated the "pull up" resistor for every pins of Port C. But still, when I compare the PC5 to 1, I don't get the expected result.

I know the proper way is to do the comparison using the bit-masking.

```
if((PORTC &(1<<PORTC5))==0).
```

But I can't figure out why the code presented above doesn't work.

I feel like I am missing some fundamentals in bit-wise operators but can't figure out what exactly. Thank you!!

The datasheet of Atmega 328P says the following:

> All registers and bit references in this section are written in general form. A lower case “x” represents
>   the numbering letter for the port, and a lower case “n” represents the bit number. However,
>   when using the register or bit defines in a program, the precise form must be used. For example,
>   PORTB3 for bit no. 3 in Port B, here documented generally as PORTxn.

Comment: What is the definition of PINC5?

Comment: PINC5 is just a constant which indicated which bit of PORTC matches PC5. It is not the value of that bit.

Comment: Where is it defined?

Comment: Look here https://github.com/vancegroup-mirrors/avr-libc/blob/master/avr-libc/include/avr/iom328p.h and see that PINC5 is a constant number equal to 5. And to read pin state you need to use a PINC register in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PINC5 and PORTC5 are defines that equate to 5. So the code does not read status of pins of IO port C at all to get the status of the bits, it is just comparing if number 5 is number 1 and it never is. Also, PORTC is the output data register. If you want to read status of a pushbutton, you must read PINC register.

Comment: Got it!! Thanks a lot @Justme

Comment: @JuneStar_2918 I use ARM, not AVR, but with my compiler, with the way the built in register definitions are defined, I can't actually go "if(Register->Bit == 1)" or "if(Register->Bit == true)". I actually have to go "if(Register->Bit)" or "if(!Register->Bit)". Just so you know what's out there.